# Replacing a weird single-quote (’) with blank string in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to use `string.replace('’','')` to replace the dreaded weird single-quote character: ’ (aka \xe2 aka #8217). But when I run that line of code, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file
```

**EDIT**: I get this error when trying to replace characters in a CSV file obtained remotely.

```
# encoding: utf-8

import urllib2

# read raw CSV data from URL
url = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.aaphoenix.org/meetings/aa_meetings.csv')
raw = url.read()

# replace bad characters
raw = raw.replace('’', "")

print(raw)
```

Even after the above code is executed, the unwanted character still exists in the print result. I tried the suggestions in the below answers as well. Pretty sure it's an encoding issue, but I just don't know how to fix it, so of course any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I really appreciate the attempts to answer this, but the answers did not fix the issue. I have edited my question with more detail and code to hopefully help.

Comment: Yes, I did. Same result.

Comment: What if you use `raw.replace('’'.decode('utf-8'), "")`? What about `raw.replace(unichr(8217), "")`?

Comment: I didn't try it, but the answer below worked perfect for my situation.

Comment: @agf that worked for me -- and `unichr(8216)` for the left-side single quote.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem here is with the encoding *of the file you downloaded* (`aa_meetings.csv`).  The server doesn't declare an encoding in its HTTP headers, but the only non-ASCII<sup>1</sup> octet in the file has the value 0x92.  You say that this is supposed to be "the dreaded weird single-quote character", therefore the file's encoding is [`windows-1252`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).  But you're trying to search and replace for the UTF-8 encoding of U+2019, i.e. `'\xe2\x80\x99'`, which is not what is in the file.

Fixing this is as simple as adding appropriate calls to `encode` and `decode`:

```
# encoding: utf-8
import urllib2

# read raw CSV data from URL
url = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.aaphoenix.org/meetings/aa_meetings.csv')
raw = url.read().decode('windows-1252')

# replace bad characters
raw = raw.replace(u'’', u"'")

print(raw.encode("ascii"))
```

<sup>1</sup> by "ASCII" I mean "the character encoding which maps single octets with values 0x00 through 0x7F directly to U+0000 through U+007F, and does not define the meaning of octets with values 0x80 through 0xFF".

Answer (score 8):

You have to [declare the encoding](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations) of your source file.
Put this as one of the first two lines of your code:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

If you are using an encoding other than UTF-8 (for example Latin-1), you have to put that instead.

Answer (score 3):

This file is encoded in Windows-1252. The apostrophe `U+2019` encodes to `\x92` in this encoding. The proper thing is to decode the file to Unicode for processing:

```
data = open('aa_meetings.csv').read()
assert '\x92' in data
chars = data.decode('cp1252')
assert u'\u2019' in chars
fixed = chars.replace(u'\u2019', '')
assert u'\u2019' not in fixed
```

The problem was you were searching for a UTF-8 encoded `U+2019`, i.e. `\xe2\x80\x99`, which was not in the file. Converting to Unicode solves this.

Using unicode literals as I have here is an easy way to avoid this mistake. However, you can encode the character directly if you write it as `u'’'`:

```
Python 2.7.1
>>> u'’'
u'\u2019'
>>> '’'
'\xe2\x80\x99'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do `string.replace('\xe2', "'")` to replace them with the normal single-quote.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting such `Non-ASCII character '\xe2'` errors repeatedly with my Python scripts, despite replacing the single-quotes. It turns out **the non-ASCII character really was a double en dash (−−)**. I replaced it with a regular double dash (--) and that fixed it. [Both will look the same on most screens. Depending on your font settings, the problematic one might look a bit longer.]

For anyone encountering the same issue in their Python scripts (in their lines of code, not in data loaded by your script):

**Option 1: get rid of the problematic character**

- Re-type the line by hand. (To make sure you did not copy-paste the problematic character by mistake.)
- Note that commenting the line out will not work.
- Check whether the problematic character really is the one you think.

**Option 2: change the encoding**

Declare an encoding at the beginning of the script, as Roberto pointed out:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Hope this helps someone.